# Can't insert path and file name in the footer

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I am trying to insert the path and file name in the footer (I am in Design mode) under Quick Parts, but the Document Property is greyed out and I can't access it.

How do I insert this info into the footer?

Comment: I am not sure why it is grayed out but I found [this tutorial](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-word/archive/2010/08/04/add-the-filename-to-your-header-or-footer.aspx), please follow the instructions and tell me if the problem continues.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Word 2007 format? The Document Property feature doesn't work with older formats. In this case you'd have to go with old-style document properties (using fields, via Insert - Quick Parts - Field - DocProperty) to insert.

If you can see the phrase [Compatibility mode] next to the file name in the title bar of the window, you can't add any type of Document Property into the document at all. You can convert documents in an old format by clicking the office logo in the top left of the screen and choose "Convert" menu item.